# Reading key/value mapping from a file into a gradle build

Tags: gradle

Given a text file in one of the following formats:

```
key1="value"
key2=10
```

or:

```
key1: "value"
key2: 10
```

or JSON:

```
{
  "key1": "value",
  "key2": 10
}
```

how can I read this information into a variable of type `Map` in a `gradle` build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E.g. this way:

**build.gradle**

```
def loadProperties = { filename -> 
    def properties = new Properties()
    file(filename).withInputStream {
        properties.load(it)
    }
    return properties
}

println loadProperties('lol.properties').key1
```

**lol.properties**

```
key1="value"
key2=10
```

For JSON you can use `JsonSlurper`. Don't know the second format.

Comment: it worked for me. I had to use a composed key like com.lib.token_lib=hashValue and I imported it as loadProperties('custom_file.properties').getProperty("com.lib.token_lib")